# xUnit Assert.All() async

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net, xunit2

I have this example test using [xUnit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit/2.2.0-beta2-build3300):

```
    [Fact]
    public void SomeTest()
    {
        Assert.All(itemList, async item=>
                {
                    var i = await Something(item);
                    Assert.Equal(item,i);
                });
    }
```

Is there a good solution to make the whole test async/awaitable?

Comment: Change your test method signature to `public async Task SomeTest()`

Comment: @Igor: That change only makes `SomeTest()` superficially awaitable.  `Assert.All()` still behaves the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for 2023, accepted answer is no longer true, xunit team added `Assert.AllAsync`:
https://github.com/xunit/xunit/discussions/2498

Comment: Applies to XUnit 2.4.2+

Answer (score 33):

In xUnit 2.4.2 and above, use `Assert.AllAsync`. Otherwise, you can use `Task.WhenAll`:

```
[Fact]
public async Task SomeTest()
{
    var itemList = ...;
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(itemList.Select(async item =>
    {
        var i = await Something(item);
        return i;
    }));
    Assert.All(results, result => Assert.Equal(1, result));
}
```